# In java, is there a way to combine String.contain() and String.equals() to print out a certain character when given another?

Tags: java, string, char

I was working on some java code that prints out "secret code" when you input a certain phrase. ("Hello" would print "itssg", a=q, b=w, c=e, etc)

I got through part of it only to realize I can't use `String.contain()` or `String.equals()` if I want the corresponding letters printed out.

Is there someway to combine the two to make the letters match up to the secret code?

Here's part of the code:

```
String r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
  "Enter the text you want to be turned into secret code.\n\n The secret code will print out at the bottom of your screen.");

if ("A".equals(r) || "a".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("q");
} else {}

if ("B".equals(r) || "b".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("w");
} else {}

if ("C".equals(r) || "c".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("e");
} else {}
if ("D".equals(r) || "d".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("r");
}

if ("E".equals(r) || "e".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("t");
}

if ("F".equals(r) || "f".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("y");
}

if ("G".equals(r) || "g".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("u");
}

if ("H".equals(r) || "h".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("i");
}

if ("I".equals(r) || "i".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("o");
}

if ("J".equals(r) || "j".equals(r)) {
 System.out.print("p");
}
```

Comment: Does `o` map to `i`? And `q` to `a`?

Comment: I'm still not completely sure of the question, I'm trying to print a 'q' when there's an 'a' and I'm trying to print an 'o' when there's an 'i'

Comment: There are *many* ways to do this. What is the variable `r`? You are comparing strings.  You may want to create a map of characters.

Comment: Variable r is the joptionpane input dialog string

Comment: I have never created a map of characters. Can I find a guide to that somewhere?

Comment: If you move your test schema into a method like `void icp (String upper, String res) {
    if (upper.equals (r) || upper.toLowerCase ().equals (r)) 
        System.out.print (res);
} `, you can reduce the testing rows neat little `icp ("A", "q");` calls, where all input and output characters align. The next step is, to put both into an array `String[] ins = {"A", "B", "C", ...}; outs = ...` and then iterate with one loop over them. Why Strings at all, and not characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was surprised when I found the mapping origin, it's qwerty! You can map each character to its' lower case corresponding position on the keyboard. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mapStr = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm", phrase = "Hello";
    for (char ch : phrase.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(mapStr.charAt(ch - 'a'));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
itssg
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but now I'm wondering if this will work with multiple letters or different symbols if I were to create more advanced secret codes. Can you only map characters if they're in the Latin alphabet, one at a time?